# Dynamic import() and render a React component module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading, code-splitting, dynamic-import

This is a Lazy Route component I wrote a while ago (code below).

This is what it does:

- It initially render a `lazyLoading = true` state to show some spinner or something.
- Then on `useEffect` it will dynamic import() a component module and set the `LazyComponent` state. Like `setLazyComponent(module)`
- Then it will turn the loading to false and render `<LazyComponent.default />`

Note: It works as intended.

**My question is:**

I've tried to do the following:

- Set the `default` property to the state. As in `setLazyComponent(module.default)`. Since `SomeComponent`, which is the component that is being lazy loaded has a single `default` export.
- Then I should be able to render just `<LazyComponent/>` instead of `<LazyComponent.default/>`
- But it **does not work**.

And I get this error:

[image]

Why does it not work? All the rest of the code is the same. The only change I'm trying to make is the place where I access the `default` property.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const LS = {};

LS.Container_DIV = styled.div`
`;

async function lazyRender() {
  const module = await import("./SomeComponent");
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(module);
  });
}

function LazyRoute(props) {
  console.log('Rendering LazyRoute...');

  const [lazyLoading,setLazyLoading] = useState(true);
  const [LazyComponent,setLazyComponent] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getLazyComponent() {
      const module = await lazyRender();
      setLazyComponent(module);
      setLazyLoading(false);
    }
    getLazyComponent();
  },[]);

  return(
    lazyLoading ?
      <div>I am Lazy Loading....</div>
    : <LazyComponent.default {...props}/>
  );
}

export default React.memo(LazyRoute);
```